# Google mock of non virtual functions in class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have tested Google Mock for `virtual` function, but am unable to do it for `non-virtual`. I didn't understand the concept of **"hi-perf dependency injection"**.

Below is class having one `non-virtual` function. I want to use Google Mock to test this function. For simplicity, I have removed core part and just kept single `return` statement.

Below is example:

```
// gtest and gmock files are added

class DetectorGPIO
{
    DetectorGPIO(void);
    virtual ~DetectorGPIO() {}
    StartPulseHigh();
};

BOOL DetectorGPIO::StartPulseHigh()
{
    return 1;
}

class MockDetectorGPIO : public DetectorGPIO
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(StartPulseHigh,BOOL(void));
};
```

Am I missing any concept?

I am new to Google Mock. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I have understood, it only mocks virtual polymorphic objects, which has always limited its usefulness to me.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you have issues compiling? If so, what is the compiler output? I'm not familiar with Google Mock myself, but looking at your source code: You are using ```StartPulseHigh```, but it doesn't seem to be defined in your ```DetectorGPIO``` class.

Comment: @Freakyy, Actually I forgot to add definition in class. i have added now.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about hi-perf dependency injection in [Google Mock Cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md). I think it clearly describes proper way of using this concept.

In this type of mocking your `MockDetectorGPIO` does not need to inherit from `DetectorGPIO`. In place where you want to use concrete class (or mock) you should use templates:

```
template <class Detector>
void ConfigureDetectorGPIO(Detector* pDetector)
{
    pDetector->StartPulseHigh();
}
```

Note that in Google Mock you are not obligated to mock existing methods.